Enigmatic Musical Word Search
Here's a musical word search that I put together with an answer that's a single word. Good luck!
Move to the Music
I started where I am, but then I have to move.


Creedence brought 5 cents here.
An irreplaceable opening line.
A kool group’s dance invitation.
This artist is too sexy.
This rida isn’t dead or alive.
What is that Thames crossing doing?
Beastlie advocacy.
Stride on Io and boogie.
What forces a stone not to stop?
BGG says siblings & parents do this.

Word Search as Table (ignore header):
















S
T
R
W
E
L
H
C
K


L
M
U
E
G
P
M
A
T


E
F
T
O
R
Y
L
P
A


S
L
I
F
P
A
N
B
V


R
B
M
S
L
E
U
Q
M


E
A
T
E
C
O
W
J
E


N
D
H
L
K
R
O
P
S


L
U
S
P
E
O
F
E
H


M
D
R
A
L
U
W
G
R




I tried to do that by having the description of the image be just the text, but I guess that didn't work. I couldn't quite get the formatting right when I tried the markdown table earlier, but I can try it again. Would you be able to help me figure out that formatting? I can't seem to get it to appear as a word search otherwise (just a table with a few extra rows on top for headings that shouldn't be there).

Instead of some silly variation of word-search, this puzzle turned out to be a very cunningly set enigmatic-puzzle with a delightfully thematic solution waiting at the end.
Let's do the clues first:
Creedence brought 5 cents here.

 "Bring a nickel, tap your feet" - CCR: Down on the corner

An irreplaceable opening line.

 "To the left, to the left" - Beyoncé: Irreplaceable

A kool group’s dance invitation.

 Kool and the Gang: Get down on it

This artist is too sexy.

 Right Said Fred: I'm Too Sexy

This rida isn’t dead or alive.

 Flo Rida: Right Round
 (borrows heavily from the Dead or Alive song You spin me round (like a record))

What is that Thames crossing doing?

  Trad: London Bridge is falling down

Beastlie advocacy.

 Beastie Boys: Fight for your right (Thanks, @Stiv!)

Stride on Io and boogie.

 Walk the Moon: Shut Up and Dance (Thanks again, @Stiv!)

What forces a stone not to stop?

 "If you start me up, I'll never stop" - The Rolling Stones: Start Me Up

BGG says siblings & parents do this.

 "Whether you're a brother or whether you're a mother /
 You're stayin' alive" - BoardGameGeek Bee Gees: Staying alive

The theme seems clear at this point, so as the intro suggests, "I started where I am, but then I have to move"
In other words, we should

 Start at the letter I, (or possibly at "I'm") and move to the direction suggested in the solution of each clue.

Following this track we find the clue phrase already suggested by @yuzuo:

 I'M BREATHLESS


which is a 1990 album by

 Madonna.

Combining all this with the theme of the puzzle, the final one-word answer must then be the final track of this album:

 "Let your body move to the music (move to the music)" - Madonna: Vogue


Ooh, this makes a lot of sense! As would 'Beastlie advocacy' being this...

Also, I think 'Stride on Io' leads to this. This would then make this perfectly compatible with yuzuo's answer too (and final suggestion of 'stayin' for the last step...

This is a terrific start, keep it up!

Great solve! Thanks for sticking with it to the end (and for the kind words about the puzzle itself).

Here is the solution (with some clues unsolved).
I believe all the clues point in

 the direction (based on the flavor text's "have to move").

Then, it's not hard to notice that

 the entire grid contains only one "I," corresponding to the flavor text's "I started where I am." So we need to start from the "I" and move according to the directions.

Part of the clues' answers are below:

 Creedence brought 5 cents here.-DOWN? Might refers to Creedence Clearwater Revival"Down On the Corner"
An irreplaceable opening line.-LEFT Beyoncé’s song "Irreplaceable" starts with the iconic line, "To the left, to the left."
This artist is too sexy.-RIGHT A reference to I’m Too Sexy by Right Said Fred.
This rida isn’t dead or alive.-RIGHT
What is that Thames crossing doing?-DOWN
Beastlie advocacy.-RIGHT
Stride on Io and boogie.-?
What forces a stone not to stop?-UP "If you start me up, I'll never stop" - The Rolling Stones: Start Me Up(According to @Bass)
BGG says siblings & parents do this.-STAY? The Bee Gees famously sang about family in their hit song Stayin’ Alive.

However, according to the answers and deduction I have, I could only find this in table:

 

Edit:
If the answer of An irreplaceable opening line. could be

 LEFTLEFT,because the line is "To the left, to the left."

and we can extract……

 

So the answer clue phrase might be……

 IM BREATHLESS

And the answer might be……

 MADONNA!


Super impressive! I think you've nearly gotten it all and you've reached the correct phrase from the word search itself, but there's actually one more step to get to the final answer.

Alright, I  add the further step you might expect!

Oh, still so close! That's definitely a connection you can make, but the final answer is more specific still.
